# Set selected item class to active in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am working on an application where I have to set item class to active but Its not working. It's not in the ng-repeat list. Its 4 normal button that has to be active when clicked on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try achieving this by ng-class as shown below.

**Controller**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.isActive = false;
  $scope.activeButton = function() {
    $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
  }  
});
```

**CSS**

```
$base: #F8E1C2;
$button: #3D3240;
$button-active: #FF735C;
$margin: 40px;

body {
  background: $base;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  padding: $margin;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  padding: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: $button;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.active {
  background: $button-active;
}
.disabled {
  background: #eee;
  color: #aaa;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button class="button" ng-class="{'active': isActive}" ng-click="activeButton()" type="button">Click Me</button> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove single quotes on class name active, like from 'active' to active